# Work with foregorund services on One UI 6 firmware

Tags: android, foreground-service, android-14

everyone. Has anyone encountered the error on Android 14: MissingForegroundServiceTypeException, especially on Samsung devices? In our app we are using a foreground service, and all the necessary permissions and service type are specified in the manifest. I also specify the service type when launching it. The peculiar thing is that everything works fine on Pixel devices with Android 14, but on Samsung devices with One UI 6, the application crashes.

I tried to find articles on this problem on various Internet resources and forums, including official documentation from Google and Samsung, but to no avail.

Comment: need a formatting . please go through how to ask question tour .